# ElasticSearch Nest Client initialize results var

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using the Nest client to query ElasticSearch and according to a parameter I create different queries using a switch statement

```
switch (parameter)
{
    case 1:
    var results = this.ConnectedClient.Search<ElasticSearchProject>(...
    break;
    case 2:
    var results = this.ConnectedClient.Search<ElasticSearchProject>(...
    break;
}
```

When I try to process the results outside the case statement I can't because the results var does not exist in this context.

I tried to declare the results var outsize the case but it has to be initialized.

How can I work out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I use a `SearchDescriptor` class and set the required search settings on that and pass it to my `Search` method call.

So for your example.

```
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchProject>();
 //You can also set options here like Types, Indexes, Fields, Rows, Start

 switch (parameter)
 {
     case 1:
        //Set parameter 1 specific search options here...
        searchDescriptor.Query(...
        break;
     case 2:
        //Set parameter 2 specific search options here...
        searchDescriptor.Query(...
        break;
 } 

 var results = this.ConnectdClient.Search<ElasticSearchProject>(searchDescriptor);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its exactly what I wanted.